# How to select float values of 1 decimal points in a range of float values with 2 decimal points

Tags: python

Say I have a range of float values from `0.18` to `0.22` as `[0.18,  0.19,  0.20,  0.21,  0.22]` and I want to devise a way to select `0.20` (the float value with 0 in its last decimal place, how do I do that in that range, or any other range?

Comment: Format it as a string with 2 values after the decimal and check if the fourth number is a 0. `for i in your_list: if "{:0.2f}".format(i)[3] == "0": return i`

Comment: what have you tried so far? There are at least several approaches you could take. check whether the rounded value == the natural value? cast to string and use regex or check for length/last digit == 0, etc.

Comment: `[i for i in your_list if round(i,1)==i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you.

```
for num in list:
    if num==round(num,1):
        print(num)
```

Main idea here is to round the number to single decimal point and to check if it is equal to original number.

Answer (score 1):

0.20 or any number that is ending by 0 can be found using **modulo** operator (%). So I would do something like this :

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.21, 0.22])

boolean_mask = (np.array(a) % 0.10) == 0

print(a[boolean_mask])
```

**Output:**

```
np.array([0.20])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an integer conversion or rounding rather than a modulo with a float divisor:

For example:

```
a = 3.5
b = 3.56

int(a*10) == a*10  # True
int(b*10) == b*10  # False

a % 0.1 == 0 # False (should be True)
```

*Note that `round(a,1) == a` or `if not a*10%1:` would also work*.